# This method must return a result of type int -

Tags: java, eclipse, class, methods, this

All is working fine apart from the last method `getPrice()` I am returning `int` but I keep getting the same error. Also if I set warranty to be false it still returns (base+((base/100)*10))

```
public class Machinery extends SaleGroup {

private float serial;
public int base;
private static boolean hasWarranty;

public Machinery(String newItemDescription, float newProductCode,
        float newSerial, int newBasePrice) {

    super(newItemDescription, newProductCode);
    serial = newSerial;
    base = newBasePrice;

}

public boolean IncludeWarranty() {
    return hasWarranty=true;
}

public boolean ExcludeWarranty() {
    return hasWarranty=false;
}

public float getSerial() {
    return serial;
}



public int getPrice()
    {
        if (hasWarranty==true)
        {
            return (base+((base/100)*10));
        } 
        else if (hasWarranty==false) 
        {
            return base;
        }
    }
}
```

I have 3 classes, SaleGroup.java, Machinery.java and MachineryTest.java

```
public abstract class SaleGroup {

     private String item;
     private float code;

     //Constructor with name and code parameters for specifying 
     //access methods that return the name and code
     public SaleGroup(String newItemDescription, float newProductCode)
     {
          item = newItemDescription;
          code = newProductCode;
     }

     public String getItemDescription() 
     {
          return item;
     }

     public float getProductCode() 
     {
          return code;
     }

     public abstract int getPrice();

     public String toString()
     {
          return "Item " + item + "has product code " + code + " and price is" + getPrice();
     }

}
```

MachineryTest.java

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class MachineryTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String newItemDescription = "Item";
        float newSerial = 4234;
        float newProductCode = 3424;
        int newBasePrice = 1000;
        boolean hasWarranty=true;

        Machinery test1 = new Machinery(newItemDescription, newProductCode,
                newSerial, newBasePrice);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                null,
                "Item: " + test1.getItemDescription() + " Serial: "
                        + test1.getSerial() + " Code: "
                        + test1.getProductCode() + " Warranty Included: "
                        + hasWarranty + " Price " + test1.getPrice());
    }
}
```

**Update: **

All is working fine apart from the last method getPrice() I am returning int but I keep getting the same error. Also if I set warranty to be false it still returns (base+((base/100)*10))

Comment: I think you're confusing compile-time errors with runtime errors

Comment: Next time, PLEASE don't erase your previous code and replace it with two lines that isn't understandable without the rest of the context. And also, if the original question is solved then you should probably mark an answer as accepted and ask a new question.

Answer (score 5):

If neither of your `if` conditions is true, the method won't return anything.
The compiler's reachability analysis is not smart enough to realize that `bool`s must always be `true` or `false` (especially since that's not quite true)

You can fix this by removing the `if` from the `else` clause.
While you're at it, you can also remove the `== true` part, which is useless.

Comment: Ok did as you told me but base is not changing according to whether or not warranty is true.  I need base to be (base+((base/100)*10)) if warranty is true else return base..

i.e. if base is 1000 and warranty is true then returns 1100

if warranty is false it returns 1000

Comment: The code is working correct, but we cannot make assumptions about the specs of what the code should do. But is easy enough to assign the calculated value to base before returning it, if that is the result of the method. But, if you do that, your method is doing two things: 1) calculating the new price and 2) returning a price. Better split it into 2 methods.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the compiler won't work out that this:

```
if (hasWarranty == true) {
   ...
} else if (hasWarranty == false) {
   ...
}
```

will always execute exactly *one* of those paths. It thinks you might get to the end of the `if` statement without taking either brance, which means that you could get to the end of the method without returning anything. Indeed, it would be possible for `hasWarranty` to be `false` to start with, then another thread to change it to `true` before the second condition was executed.

You could just remove the second condition:

```
if (hasWarranty == true)  {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

And you can also remove the comparison with boolean literals:

```
if (hasWarranty) {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

You should also consider using a *conditional operator*:

```
public int getPrice() {
    return hasWarranty ? base + ((base/100) * 10) : base;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public int getPrice()
{
    if (hasWarranty==true)
    {
         return (base+((base/100)*10));
    }
    else {
         return base;
    }
}
```

If you're already testing for the true case, the the else will automatically be the false case. Only two possible cases, true and false.  This way the compile knows there will always be something returned. If your code, the compile doesn't know if the code will return anything because the returns are encapsulated with conditions.

Comment: You might like to say why this is better.

Comment: Ok did as you told me but base is not changing according to whether or not warranty is true.  I need base to be (base+((base/100)*10)) if warranty is true else return base..

i.e. if base is 1000 and warranty is true then returns 1100

if warranty is false it returns 1000

Comment: Check @Peter Lawry 's answer. He has your solution to that.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to SLaks answer just change the code like this, to compile successfully:

```
 if (hasWarranty)
 {
      return (base+((base/100)*10));
 }
 else 
 {
      return base;
 }
```

Second `if` is redundant.

Comment: @BackSlash, yes, I edited. :)

Comment: Ok did as you told me but base is not changing according to whether or not warranty is true.  I need base to be (base+((base/100)*10)) if warranty is true else return base..

i.e. if base is 1000 and warranty is true then returns 1100

if warranty is false it returns 1000

Answer (score 0):

```
public int getPrice()
{
     if (hasWarranty==true)
     {
          return (base+((base/100)*10));
     }
     else if (hasWarranty==false) {
          return base;

     }
}
```

if both the `if` and `else-if` is `false` the function is not being able to evaluate return anything, whither either of them will be `true` can't be evaluated until the run-time. Hence, the body of  function `getPrice()` can complete normally and a compile time error results.

This is specified in [jls-8.4.7 Method body](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.7):

> If a method is declared to have a return type, then a *compile-time
>   error occurs* if the body of the method can complete normally. In
>   other words, a method with a return type must return only by using a
>   return statement that provides a value return; it is not allowed to
>   **"drop off the end of its body"**.

So:

```
public int getPrice()
    {
         if (hasWarranty==true)
         {
              return (base+((base/100)*10));
         }

       return base;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler doesn't know the second `if` statement is redundant and pointless.  In general, if the code confuses the compiler, its confusing code.  You can write

```
public int getPrice() {
     if (hasWarranty==true) {
          return (base+((base/100)*10));
     }
     return base;
}
```

or

```
public int getPrice() {
     return base + (hasWarranty ? (base/100)*10 : 0);
}
```

BTW `/100*10` is not the same as `*10/100` or `/10`  I suspect you wanted to add 10% and the best way to do that is `base/10`

```
public int getPrice() {
     return base + (hasWarranty ? base/10 : 0);
}
```

---

Having a `getPrice()` method doesn't magically change the `base` field.  If you want the price you need to call the method.

```
public class Priced {
    int base = 1000;
    boolean hasWarranty = true;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Priced priced = new Priced();
        System.out.println("price: " + priced.getPrice() + ", hasWarranty: " + priced.hasWarranty);
        priced.hasWarranty = false;
        System.out.println("price: " + priced.getPrice() + ", hasWarranty: " + priced.hasWarranty);
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return base + (hasWarranty ? base / 10 : 0);
    }
}
```

prints

```
price: 1100, hasWarranty: true
price: 1000, hasWarranty: false
```

Comment: Thanks peter i tried it as u told me but still with the same problem..  warranty is set as true, but it returns base as 1000 not 1100... :/

Comment: @JohnSmith In that case you are doing something wrong like getting the `base` instead of calling `getPrice()` See my updated answer.

Comment: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Item: "+test1.getItemDescription() + " Serial: "+ test1.getSerial() + " Code: "+ test1.getProductCode() + " Warranty Included: "+ hasWarranty + " Price " + test1.getPrice());

Comment: @JohnSmith Can you include `test1.hasWarranty` ?

Comment: I expected `hasWarranty` to be non-static.  If this is a global setting, the methods to use it/alter it should also be `static`,

Comment: Are you sure there is no other `hasWarranty` field involved, either locally or in a parent class? What do you see when you debug your code?

Comment: Is it possible to send u a private msg or something?

Comment: You need more reputation to chat.  Just post here as a comment. Or update your question if there is significant details others might use.

Comment: I will update my question

Comment: @JohnSmith I have updated my answer.  Most likely you have more than one `hasWarranty` field and you are setting a different one to the one used.